# Implementing NASA-TLX in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

The NASA-TLX test, short version, is fully coded in HTML and Javascript [here.](http://jensgrubert.bplaced.net/nasa-tlx-short/TLX-English-short.html) Unfortunately, it uses a lot of inline JavaScript to accomplish the UI responsiveness.

To move the functions into Meteor without recreating them, I've attempted to put them into a `Template.nasatlx_form.rendered` callback:

```
Template.nasatlx_form.rendered = function() {
// Everything from <head> would go in here to render. snipped
function scaleClick(index, val)
    {
        results_rating[index] = val;

        // Turn background color to white for all cells
        for (i = 5; i <= 100; i += 5)
        {
            var top = "t_" + index + "_" + i;
            var bottom = "b_" + index + "_" + i;
            document.getElementById(top).bgColor='#FFFFFF';
            document.getElementById(bottom).bgColor='#FFFFFF';
        }

        var top = "t_" + index + "_" + val;
        var bottom = "b_" + index + "_" + val;
        document.getElementById(top).bgColor='#AAAAAA';
        document.getElementById(bottom).bgColor='#AAAAAA';
    }
}
```

But this doesn't appear to be the correct way to implement it, as any of the functions are throwing undeclared errors. Should `Template.nasatlx_form.events` used exclusively to make these declarations?

Comment: `rendered` (which is called `onRendered` these days) should be the right place for this, but you need to add more info to show why it isn't working before anyone can help, I think.

Comment: It's possible that you could add the js file to `client/compatibility` and just run it vanilla from there as an alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that you could add the js file to `client/compatibility` and just run it vanilla from there as an alternative.

Comment: Took the inline JS and added it to a .js file in client/compatibility, which resolved the issue without creating a new `eventMap` for it. Thank you!